# Error Uploading File using IOS Cordova

Tags: php, ios, cordova

I am facing pretty strange error . I made a code using cordova .My Server is on Amazon cloud . I am trying to take the picture and upload it to the server . The code works fine when i upload the picture from android phone but when i try to upload the picture through iOS it give me 200 ok response from the server and image is not uploaded .

Here is my code

```
            var params = {};
            params.usertoken = window.localStorage.ukey;
            params.status = "public";
            fileURI = window.localStorage.fileuri;

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            //options.fileKey = "userfile";
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            alert(fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();

            ft.upload(fileURI,"http://xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com/ucheck/upload.php", win, fail, options);
```

On the server i have this code

```
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./".$new_image_name);
```

**What I DID**

I putt the same code on go daddy and amazon server . On godaddy server the image uploaded and amazon its not . I further look out server side and when i print the $_FILES

on godaddy i get this

```
  Array
  (
   [file] => Array
     (
        [name] => cdv_photo_017.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpODHKQy
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 3136377
    )

 )
```

On amazon i get this

```
Array
(
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => cdv_photo_018.jpg
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 1
        [size] => 0
    )
```

)

Error Code Indicate this => Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. 
[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

This only happening with IOS with android the file upload work with same server .

Below are the installed plugin

```
   org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera"
   org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.12 "Console"
   org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.13 "Device"
   org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2 "File"
   org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.8 "File Transfer"
   org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.11 "Geolocation"
   org.apache.cordova.media 0.2.15 "Media"
   org.apache.cordova.media-capture 0.3.5 "Capture"
```

Do you think i need to change something in the config.xml file ?

Comment: If you say "Value: 1;The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize ", and it works on android, maybe the iOS pictures are bigger than the android ones

Comment: Thanks for the message . I check that too the image size is 1.4mb . Which is not big . On Andriod it send me more than 3 mb file and server store it too . One more thing when i try to upload 90kb file it uploaded smoothly from  iPhone and i also get all the parameters on server

Comment: @jcesarmobile : I get the same error but only size is zero. Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => cdv_photo_018.jpg [type] => image/jpg [tmp_name] => tmp/dadqweda [error] => 0 [size] => 0 ) . Any help?